# Uploading a file isn't hitting breakpoints, and lands on a different page on submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my Upload view called `upload.cshtml` I have the following code to submit the form

```
<form asp-controller="HomeController" asp-action="UploadFile" method="post"  
      enctype="multipart/form-data">       
    <input type="file" name="file" />  
    <button type="submit">Upload File</button>  
</form>
```

And in my `HomeController.cs` I have the following

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
        return Content("file not selected");

    var path = Path.Combine(
                Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot",
                file.FileName);

    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Files");
}
```

When the form is submitted, it just goes to this page `localhost:0000/HomeController/UploadFile` and no breakpoints in `HomeController` are hit. I'm not exaggerating when I say I've been stuck on this for a week (new to CORE & MVC) so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you define the `Files` method you redirect to? `return RedirectToAction("Files");`

Comment: Perhaps change `upload.cshtml` to match your method name `uploadfile.cshtml`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, honestly as this was taken from numerous tutorials, I don't see a method for `Files`. However, as it's hitting a breakpoint, and the submission of the input doesn't take me to `Files`. I presumed this wouldn't matter at this point. I tried renaming the file, but I had no luck.

Comment: Can you try change the `asp-controller="Home"` instead of `HomeController`

Comment: As per my investigation `asp-controller="HomeController"` caused the routing failure. I hope you are able to figure out that as per the suggestion by replacing it by `HomeController` to just `Home`.